# What is the convolution of an antipodal (that is alternating 1 and 0) pulse train with rectangular pulse of duration T in the time domain?

Tags: convolution

What is the convolution of an antipodal (that is alternating 1 and -1) pulse train with a rectangular pulse of duration T in the time domain?  I am having trouble picturing this.

Comment: Look up "square wave" and you'll find images to help you picture it.  I'm going to go look up what convolution means other than the standard definition, but this looks like a homework question, which means there is a minimum standard of effort.  Show your attempt at a solution.  How would you solve a convolution problem for a DC voltage or for a sine wave or triangle wave?

Comment: Ok I had to look that up.  If you check out the wikipedia article on convolution, they've provided visual examples.  The convolution appears to be a formula for the overlapping area as you move one pulse shape past the other.

Comment: Not a homework problem, I am in industry, I literally have no idea.

Comment: @K H, mathematically, it is a function processing another function. I vaguely remember that I need to first understand the idea of convolution before DFT/FFT.

Comment: @user4434 How will knowing the convolution help you if you don't know what it means?  Did the Wikipedia article help you?

Comment: @K H, the Wiki is hard to understand, unless you spend some hours in the function stuff. But the animation in the visual explanation does help a little bit, :) https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Convolution_of_box_signal_with_itself2.gif. You need to appreciate how the big square pulse guy "moves over" another big square pulse guy produces a new, smaller triangular guy.

Comment: Let me try my broken English to explain (Note 1) . (1)  Let us first refresh our middle school Algebra and Trigonometry. to explain what is ***a function***. (a) Let us say y = (2 * x). In functional denotation (Note 2) y = f(x), or if you like, y = double(x), where "double" is the name of the function f in our case.

Comment: (2) Now let us move on to a trigonometry function, y = sine(x). Now y is a (real) number, denoting a "ratio" of two side of a triangle, and x is also a real number, denoting the "angle", or "radian", if you like. You might to read Wiki to refresh you memory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine

Comment: (3) The animation form Wiki Sine helps: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3b/Circle_cos_sin.gif/450px-Circle_cos_sin.gif. Here is x axis is the angle or radian, y axis is the sine value. So we still have the general form y = f(x). :)

Comment: (4)  Now we will be using AC sinusoidal current wave forms to explain the convolution stuff. Those readers already forgotten what is AC wave form might like to read the following to refreshing memory: 
***Sinusoidal AC Waveforms*** - Electronics Tutorials
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/sinusoidal-waveform.html

Comment: (5) I will be using the definitions and terms in the following picture https://i.imgur.com/iW0RG0X.jpeg to explain the convolution of functions in the time domain. The OP or other visitors might like to comment (eg. 'too abstract", "so far so good"), or make suggestions (eg. speed up, or slow down), before I move on.  Cheers.

Comment: Do you understand the process of correlation?

Comment: Is the system continuous-time or discrete-time system? Please provide a clear, well drawn picture of both the signals. Pleas add all the things you have already tried out to find tbe answer.

Comment: The answer strongly depends on the time gap between impulses and time duration of the rectangular pulse. If the impulses are spaced far apart in time/samples, the result is just a pulse train with same spacing. If not, the result is probably a mixture of staircases.